# Enviar headers con sockets en Python

Tags: python, http, socket, tcp, cabeceras-http

Estoy creando un servidor web con Python, multihilo, necesito enviar correctamente los headers de mis archivos (obviamente no lo hago bien porque no me funciona). Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import os
import datetime

# Para conocer el tipo del archivo:
def contentType(file):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        return "text/plain"
    elif file.endswith(".html") or file.endswith(".htm"):
        return "text/html"
    elif file.endswith(".gif"):
        return "image/gif"
    elif file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
        return "image/jpeg"
    else:
        return "application/octet-stream"


# Empezamos con la función del multihilo:
def hilo(cliente):
    # Ahora recibimos el mensaje, el cual vá por líneas, así que lo separamos
    mensaje = cliente.recv(4096).decode('UTF-8').split("\n")

    # La solicitud que se hace a nuestro servidor es la siguiente:
    solicitud = mensaje[0].split()

    # El formato que tiene que tener:
    # GET/HEAD   archivo   HTTP/1.1
    fecha = str(datetime.date.today())

    # Por defecto:
    fichero = '/'

    # En el caso que exista:
    if len(solicitud) == 3 and len(solicitud[1]) > 1 and solicitud[1].__contains__('/'):
        fichero = solicitud[1][1:]


    # Caso en el que todo está bien:
    if len(solicitud) == 3 and solicitud[0] in ['GET', 'HEAD'] and os.path.exists(fichero) and len(fichero) >1:
        fichero = solicitud[1][1:]
        codigo = '200 OK\r\n'
#        enviar = str('HTTP/1.1\r' + codigo + 'Solicitud recibida\r' + 'Date: {}'.format(fecha) + 'Server: Diego, ' + 'localhost' + '\r' + 
#                     'Content-Length:' + str(os.path.getsize(fichero)) + '\rContent-Type:' + str(contentType(fichero)) + 
#                     '\rLast-Modified: ' + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichero)).strftime("""%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z""")) +
#                     '\r')
        cliente.send(str('HTTP/1.1 ' + codigo).encode())
        cliente.send(str('Content-Type:' + str(contentType(fichero)) + '\r').encode())
        cliente.send(str('Date: {}'.format(fecha) + '\r').encode())
        cliente.send(str('Server: Diego, ' + 'localhost').encode())
        cliente.send(str('Content-Length:' + str(os.path.getsize(fichero)) + '\r').encode())
        cliente.send(str('Last-Modified: ' + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichero)).strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")) +'\r').encode())


    # 404
    elif len(solicitud) != 3 or solicitud[0] not in ['GET', 'HEAD']:
        codigo = '400 Bad Request\r'
        enviar = str('HTTP/1.1\r ' + codigo + 'Solicitud recibida\r' + 'Date: {}'.format(fecha) + 'Server: Diego, ' + 'localhost' + '\r')




        cliente.send(enviar.encode())   



    # Caso en el que está bien formado, pero no tenemos el archivo solicitado
    elif not os.path.exists(solicitud[1][1:]):
        codigo = '404  Not Found\r'
        enviar = str('HTTP/1.1\r ' + codigo + 'Solicitud recibida\r' + 'Date: {}'.format(fecha) + 'Server: Diego, ' + 'localhost' + '\r')


        cliente.send(enviar.encode())

#    print(enviar)

#    cliente.send(enviar.encode())
    cliente.close()


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Formato ServidorTCP <puerto>")
        sys.exit()

    try:
        ip = "localhost"

        port = int(sys.argv[2])


        # Creamos el socket del servidor TCP:
        socketServidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # Lo vinculamos al puerto con la función bind()
        socketServidor.bind((ip, port))

        # Establecemos un *timeout*
        socketServidor.settimeout(30)

        # Ponemos el servidor en modo escucha:
        socketServidor.listen()

        # Creamos un bucle infinito
        while True:
            # Recibimos la petición
            socketCliente, address = socketServidor.accept()

            threading.Thread(target = hilo, args = (socketCliente,)).start()


    # Controlamos la excepción por timeout y cualquier otra excepción posible
    except socket.timeout:
        print("60 segundos sin recibir nada.")

    except:
        print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise



    # Cerramos el socket:
    finally:
        socketServidor.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Funciona todo correctamente (más o menos); el único problema que tengo es al enviar los headers:

```
cliente.send(str('HTTP/1.1 ' + codigo).encode())
        cliente.send(str('Content-Type:' + str(contentType(fichero)) + '\r').encode())
        cliente.send(str('Date: {}'.format(fecha) + '\r').encode())
        cliente.send(str('Server: Diego, ' + 'localhost').encode())
        cliente.send(str('Content-Length:' + str(os.path.getsize(fichero)) + '\r').encode())
        cliente.send(str('Last-Modified: ' + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichero)).strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")) +'\r').encode())
```

La cosa está en que leyendo el archivo (lee cual es correctamente), pueda enviar los headers que le corresponden al propio archivo. He probado a enviarlos en varios formatos (como se puede apreciar en el código), pero sigue sin funcionar, por lo que supongo que no los envío en el formato correcto. La pregunta entonces es:
¿Con qué formato tengo que enviar los headers para que se leean en el destino?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que según las [especificaciones del protocolo http](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (1.1):

- Cada cabecera se especifica mediante su nombre seguido por dos puntos, un espacio en blanco y el valor, todo seguido **por un retorno de carro seguido por un salto de línea (CRLF, es decir `\r\n`)**.
- Para indicar el final de las cabeceras se usa una línea en blanco.

Es decir, no termines cada línea con `'\r'`, sino con `'\r\n'` y cuando tus headers terminen debes añadir una linea nueva en blanco: `'\r\n\r\n'`